# jboss-eap-6.1 + log4j configuration webapp

Tags: jboss-eap-6

i'm trying to set up my webapp, in order to configure log4J-1.2.17 in my jboss-eap-6.1 server in standalone mode.

is there anyone of you who may add post, a guide, a link with a concrete example to help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

JBoss EAP 6.1 uses slf4j connectors to attach to your log4j loggers. All you need to do to configure your logging behaviors in your standalone.xml is edit the urn:jboss:domain:logging subsystem. 
What do you want to do? Asking for a tutorial is not what StackOverflow is for. If you have a concrete example of what you have tried and what you are experiencing, you will get more help.

Comment: No, JBoss EAP 6.1 does not use slf4j at all. Other than that, it's try just configure logging with the logging subsystem :) Prefer the web console or CLI over editing raw XML too.